# Making a Soap Call to Given WSDL

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I have a soap server and i want to make a login request.
https://github.com/haruntuncay/soapClient In this repo, you can see generated php code from "WSDL2PHP". How can i do a proper login request.I could not get it working.You can see what i have tried in final 20 lines of server.php.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should definitively use a WSDL to php generator as I think you're not sending the request as it should be.

So using a WSDL to php generator, you will know exactly how to send the request and its associated parameters using PHP objects and the native PHP SoapClient class without having to deal directly with it.

I advise you to try the [PackageGenerator](https://github.com/WsdlToPhp/PackageGenerator) project.

Comment: Thanks for the info.I will try

Comment: Could you help me understand how to consume this wsdl -> https://test.edmbilisim.com.tr/EFaturaEDM21ea/EFaturaEDM.svc?wsdl <-. I just need to do a LoginReq but couldn't figure out how.

Comment: Did you try generating a PHP package based on the WSDL? Doing this should help you. After that, "update" your question if you encounter a new issue.

Comment: i have actually tried this -> https://github.com/haruntuncay/soapClient <-. Could you please check it out and help me correct it.

Comment: The link containt generated php code from given wsdl. At the end of the file, i tried to create a client but i failed :(

Comment: Sorry but the generated code is not as good as it could be, it's too basic and it's maybe missing features, won't help you unless you use the project I gave you, sorry. In adition, you should provide log trace and errors if you wish to have proper help.